# how to write a conditional for loop in DAX?

Tags: python, for-loop, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm using PowerBI to create a dashboard that summarizes data from a train movements simulation. (I'm a psychologist with some basic understanding of python and currently learning DAX.)
Here is some background:

- I use [index] to maintain the order of the rows
- [Notification] is a column that contains text
- [Train Nr] is a column that contains the ID of the train that the [Notification] is about
- [Standstill] is a column that contains 1 if notification is info about train coming to a standstill (otherwise 0)
- [Halt] is a column that contains 1 if notification is info about train stopping at a station (otherwise 0)

I can't figure out how to build something that would work as a for loop. In a very conceptual way this would look like this:

```
if [standstill] = 1:
       for [index] in range([index]+500):  
          if [halt] = 1 and [train nr] is the same as in the starting row: 
                 [is there halt] = 1
                 else [is there halt] = 0
```

So what I'm trying to do is finding out if for any of the rows where [stanstill] = 1 any of the next 500 rows [halt] = 1 and whether that [halt] concerns the same train as the [standstill].

Can someone help? I've tried to modify this idea: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/For-and-While-Loops-in-DAX/ba-p/636314 but at this point I'm completely stuck. If any further info is necessary, let me know.

Sample data:

| index | notification | train nr | standstill | halt | is there halt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | train nr 3345 gets status standstill | 3345 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | train nr 3345 gets status halt | 3345 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | train nr 122 position X -> Y 89076 | 122 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | train nr 122 gets status standstill | 122 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | train nr 54732 gets status riding | 54732 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 345 | train nr 122 gets status halt | 122 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

The solution can be either a measure or a column >> the most important goal is to be able to summarize the total number of instances where [standstill] = 1 and [is there halt] = 0 which means that the train is in standstill because of a red light.

Comment: Could you add some sample data with the expected output? Are you trying to build a measure or a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will attempt to answer my own question as I found a solution. This is a calculated column:

```
how many halts = 

var _index = LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Index], 'Table'[Index], [Index])
var _train = LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Train nr],'Table'[Train nr], [Train nr])
var _haltafter = FILTER('Table', [Halt]=1 && [Index] > value(_index) && [Train nr] = value(_train))

return

IF([Standstill]=1 && not ISEMPTY(_haltafter), SUMX(_haltafter, [Halt]),0)
```

The result is a number of halts that occur for the same train number after the current notification that contain info about train coming to a standstill.

Maybe this will be helpful for someone